# How to output reverse order? AJAX file > DIV

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

AIM: To output the contents of a log file line by line newest at top and oldest at bottom.

CODE:

```
<script>

$.get('http://192.168.1.1/test.log, function(data)
        {         var lines = data.split("\n");
                   $.each(lines, function(n, elem)
                       {        $('#output').append('<div>' + elem + '</div>');
                       });
         });

</script>
```

CURRENT:

This is all working fine and outputing to DIV as expected, however the bottom line is at the bottom of the div and first line at the top.

QUESTION:  How can I change the output to have the last line at the top and first line at bottom?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `.reverse()`.

```
var lines = data.split("\n").reverse();
```

---

Or if there's existing content, and the new content should go on top, use `.prepend()` instead of `.append()`.

```
$('#output').prepend('<div>' + elem + '</div>');
```